# Controling when services start in Fedora 14 GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, services

Whenever I start up my laptop running Fedora 14, I notice that it says that it is failing to connect to my default wireless network since the wireless card is not activated. Since it appears that the wireless card is not activated until the NetworkManager service is started, is there anyway for me to set NetworkManager to start before this check is made? Boot message log is attached.

http://pastebin.com/810yT456

Comment: The best description of Linux SysVinit I have found is part the Linux From Scratch documentation. Read this page, it might help you. http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.5/chapter07/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

The "Device does not seem to be present" message appears to be coming from the `network` service, which is different from the `NetworkManager` service (it uses older-style /etc/sysconfig files).

Set your system to only start the NetworkManager service. You can do this in `system-config-services`, or by running the following as root:

```
# /sbin/chkconfig network off
```

And remember that this won't disable NetworkManager, so you'll still be able to connect.